# How to I convert Timestamp in YYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss to YYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS in Hive while doing a select query?

Tags: hive, timestamp, hiveql

I am comparing timestamp columns between 2 different database engines and I need to retrieve the time stamp column stored in `YYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` format to `YYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS,` with `SSS` being `000` when no entry is there.

Can I do the above using Hive select query?

Answer (score 1):

Split the timestamp to get milliseconds part, use rpad to add zeroes if there is no millisecond part at all or milliseconds part is less that 3 digits.

Demo:

```
 with your_data as (
    select stack(3, '2019-11-02 20:18:00.123',
                    '2019-11-02 20:18:00.12',
                    '2019-11-02 20:18:00'
                ) as ts
    )

 select concat(split(ts,'\\.')[0],'.',rpad(nvl(split(ts,'\\.')[1],''),3,0))
   from your_data d 
 ;
```

Result:

```
2019-11-02 20:18:00.123
2019-11-02 20:18:00.120
2019-11-02 20:18:00.000
```

Comment: This is more powerful if there may be something behind the dot, but assuming it is all or nothing a simpler solution should also suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Given that both formats (and their lengths) are strictly defined, you can use this simple logic:

```
left(concat(ts,'.000'),19)
```

Can't check the exact syntax, but basically you append extra zeros and cut them off if you don't need them.