# hive converting string to timestamp drops millisecond information

Tags: hadoop, hive, timestamp, hiveql, unix-timestamp

I am trying to convert following string to timestamp. however not able to figure out how to handle last `milisecond part`

**String:**

```
2020-06-30T23:57:48.000-0400
```

following is working. howsoever it's loosing information about milliseconds.

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("2020-06-30T23:57:48.000-0400", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'-'SSS"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'-'SSSS");
OK
2020-06-30T23:57:48.000-0000
```

**Expected Value**

```
2020-06-30T23:57:48.000-0400
```

**update**

even this is not working

**Query**

```
hive> select date_format("2020-01-23 23:59:54.0000400", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS");
```

**output**

```
2020-01-23 23:59:54.0000000
```

Comment: unix_timestamp does not preserve milliseconds. But there are already many answers about different timestamp formats with milliseconds convertion. The idea is to extract milliseconds and concatenate with converted timestamp. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59645846/2700344 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/58713989/2700344 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/59842130/2700344 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/59528697/2700344

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

Select
concat(from_unixtime(unix_timesstamp('2020-01-23 23:59:54.0000400', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')), '.', split('2020-01-23 23:59:54.0000400', '[.]')[1]);

I hope this is helps.